# Display blank rows from a case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am writing a sql report, and one of the requirements asked of me is the inclusion of rows for both options of a CASE expression.

The report is to show the count of "Costing" and "Non-costing" transactions between all customers in the database and each of the 3 chosen customers.

Please see the example layout required.

```
CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | COSTING     | CUST_1 | CUST_2 | CUST_3
12          | Red Corp      | Non-costing | 1245   | 734    | 84
12          | Red Corp      | Costing     | 376    | 23     | 2
17          | Blue Corp     | Non-costing | 4538   | 36     | 3256
17          | Blue Corp     | Costing     | 0      | 0      | 0
...
```

I have tried putting the COSTING column within a case statement. However I cannot get the example "Blue Corp" "Costing" row to display in the output due to it being blank.

```
select  CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
        ,case 
            when PURCHASE_VALUE = 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is null then 'Non-costing'
            when PURCHASE_VALUE != 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is not null then 'Costing'
        end AS COSTING
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 11 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_1"
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 22 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_2"
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 33 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_3"
from schema.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS
group by case 
            when PURCHASE_VALUE = 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is null then 'Non-costing'
            when PURCHASE_VALUE != 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is not null then 'Costing'
        end 
        ,CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
```

I am currently getting the same as the example, but missing the 0 count row.
Please see the output I am currently getting below.

```
CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | COSTING     | CUST_1 | CUST_2 | CUST_3
12          | Red Corp      | Non-costing | 1245   | 734    | 84
12          | Red Corp      | Costing     | 376    | 23     | 2
17          | Blue Corp     | Non-costing | 4538   | 36     | 3256
...
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question? Could you provide the desired result you would expect

Comment: I am wanting it to look like the example table at the top.

Comment: And currently what output are you getting? Can you post that as well

Comment: It seems this is due to a formatting issue of your client app. What are you using to run SQL?

Comment: Please include your raw data too. It seems like there is no data for customer ID 17 which matches that condition, right? So you need to include data that doesn't exist? (Not sure I understand what you've shown anyway; how can the `count(case...)` be anything but zero, as the customer IDs don't match those rules?)

Comment: Standin.Wolf I have updated the question to include a clear example of my current output.

Comment: Alex Poole, you are correct, there is no data for "Costing" for "Blue-corp". However I want the row to display with 0s rather than not appearing at all.

Comment: The Impaler, I am using "Toad for Oracle" version 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment,

> Alex Poole, you are correct, there is no data for "Costing" for
>   "Blue-corp". However I want the row to display with 0s rather than not
>   appearing at all.

I think you need to generate the record for which one of the **costings** is not available.

I tried to create the query which will generate the record if "Costing" or "Non-costing" record is not available for any customer.

I was not able to test it so please share if you experience any issue.

```
-- Your original query starts from here
WITH DATAA AS (select  CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
        ,case 
            when PURCHASE_VALUE = 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is null then 'Non-costing'
            when PURCHASE_VALUE != 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is not null then 'Costng'
        end AS COSTING
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 11 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_1"
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 22 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_2"
,count(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 33 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "CUST_3"
from schema.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS
group by case 
            when PURCHASE_VALUE = 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is null then 'Non-costing'
            when PURCHASE_VALUE != 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is not null then 'Costing'
        end 
        ,CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME)
-- Your original query ends here


-- Solution
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    CUSTOMER_NAME,
    COSTING,
    CUST_1,
    CUST_2,
    CUST_3
FROM
    DATAA
UNION ALL
( SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    CUSTOMER_NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(CASE
            WHEN COSTING = 'Non-costing' THEN 1
        END) = 0 THEN 'Non-costing'
        WHEN COUNT(CASE
            WHEN COSTING = 'Costing' THEN 1
        END) = 0 THEN 'Costing'
    END AS COSTING,
    0,
    0,
    0
FROM
    DATAA D1
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    CUSTOMER_NAME
HAVING ( COUNT(CASE
    WHEN COSTING = 'Non-costing' THEN 1
END) = 0
         OR COUNT(CASE
    WHEN COSTING = 'Costng' THEN 1
END) = 0 )
);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is perfect, and it has solved my problem exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to add the columns:

```
select c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.CUSTOMER_NAME, t.costing,
       sum(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 11 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as CUST_1,
       sum(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 22 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as CUST_2,
       sum(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 33 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as CUST_3
from (select distinct ct.customer_id, ct.customer_name
      from schema.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS ct
     ) c cross join
     (select 'Non-costing' as costing from dual union all
      select 'Costing' from dual
     ) t left join
     schema.customer_transactions ct
     on c.customer_id = ct.customer_id,
        t.costing = (case when PURCHASE_VALUE = 0 or PURCHASE_VALUE is null
                         then 'Non-costing'
                         else 'Costing'
                     end)
group by c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.CUSTOMER_NAME, t.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.  It will give you 0 when there is none.

```
select  CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
, CASE WHEN ISNULL(PURCHASE_Value,0) = 0 THEN 'Non-costing' ELSE 'Costing' END        
,SUM(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 11 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "CUST_1"
,SUM(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 22 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "CUST_2"
,SUM(CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID = 33 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "CUST_3"
from schema.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS
group by CUSTOMER_ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
,PURCHASE_Value
```

Comment: Don't you think that this will error out as `PURCHASE_Value` is directly used in `SELECT` but not in `GROUP BY`?